# getOpenFileName in Python 3DS MAX?

Tags: python, openfiledialog, 3dsmax, maxscript, reader

I'm having a hard time to find the function getOpenFileName, which lets you basically seach for a file (OpenFileDialog basically).

I wonder if it's actually in the MaxPlus library and i would like to know if someone else knows if it's somewhere there or if there is any way to call it.

Here's an example in Maxscript:

```
f = getOpenFileName caption:"File:" \types:"Text file (*.txt)|*.txt|"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe:

```
MaxPlus.Core.EvalMAXScript('getOpenFileName caption:"File:" \types:"Text file (*.txt)|*.txt|"')
```

:)

Seriously: try DoMaxFileSaveAsDlg() from FileManager in MaxPlus

[Reference](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2015/ENU/?guid=__py_ref_class_max_plus_1_1_file_manager_html)

Comment: I tried this line too, but i'm having a bad time figuring out how to get the path as a string on the python to start reading :S. I'll let you know if i find out! :D

Comment: What is a problem with this path as string? Maybe "\" signs? Use double sign: "//" if that's it.

Comment: The problem is that i can't figure out how to get from the Maxscript command the path as value so i can onpen it inside Python.

Something like: 

`MaxPlus.Core.EvalMAXScript('file = getOpenFileName caption:"File:" \types:"Text file (*.txt)|*.txt|"')
filepath = MaxPlus.Core.EvalMAXScript('file')

print filepath`

Comment: MaxScripts are returning PFValues, just use: `filepath = MaxPlus.Core.EvalMAXScript('file').GetStr()` I cant check this until monday, but should work.
Also, You can check the path of cvurrent file in Python API, with: FileManager.GetFileNameAndPath()

Comment: I tried that too but in another way, tried your exact same way and throws invalid parameter, maybe the String convertion is called in another way now.

Answer (score 0):

4 years later, I had the same issue, here is how to do it (Here it is for a 'getSaveFileName' but the principle is the same):

```
try:
    filepath = MaxPlus.Core.EvalMAXScript('getSaveFileName \
    caption:"FBX Destination Folder" \
    types:"Object Preset(*.fbx)|*.fbx" \
    historyCategory:"FBXObjectPresets";').Get()
except:
    print("No path selected. Export Cancelled.")
    return
print("The filepath is: "+filepath)
```